# Stuck with javascript (beginner)

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning javascript and i am stuck with my first lab. I have the HTML part working but none of the javascript is working. At first I thought it did not link the javascript code to the HTML code correctly but now i think there is issues with the onload and oninput part. But have no idea why. If someone can help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab 11 suits</title>
    <script src="Lab1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<heading>
    <h1>
        HTML 5 Test Page
    </h1>
</heading>
<p id="test"></p>
<button id="button">Press Me</button>
<p/>
Colours:<select id="list">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<p/>
Your Birthday:<input type="date" id="dod"/>
A Number: <input type="range" id="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">
<span id="value">1</span>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var para = document.getElementById("heading");
    para.innerText = "A short exercise on creating dynamic web content.";
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function () {
        alert("Ive been clicked");
    };

    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.onchange = function () {
        var item = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
        changeColour(item);
    };
    var dob = document.getElementById("dob");
    dob.oninput = function () {
        alert("Your birth date is:" + dob.value);
    };
    var range = document.getElementById("range");
    var value = document.getElementById("value");
    range.onchange = function () {
        value.innerText = range.value;
    };

    function changeColour(colour) {
        var c = 0;
        switch (colour) {
            case "Red":
                c = "#f00";
                break;
            case "Green":
                c = "#0f0";
                break;
            case "Blue":
                c = "#00f";
                break;
        }
        document.bgColor = c;
    };

    function daysOld(dob) {
        var msPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            now = new Date(),
            diff = now - dob;
        return diff / msPerDay;
    };

};
```

Comment: `<script></script>` tags are missing wrapping your JS code

Comment: Welcome to stackO. You need `<script>` tags for your JS

Comment: Please have a look at [Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) first.

Comment: @kmce I've suspected that the JavaScript part is the content of the included `Lab1.js` file. If I'm wrong please rollback my edit.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What is the expected result, what is the actual result? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Yes the Javascript part is the lab1.js

Comment: Nothing happens when using it in a browser. When i click the button a pop up is meant to appear same for when i type in a DOB, but none of this happens

Comment: If you’d have taken a look into the console, you should’ve seen something like `TypeError: dob is null` or `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oninput' of null`, or the same things about `para` and `innerText`. That’s what the console is there for. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a couple of edits:

- Missing id on the `heading` element
- typo on the `id="dob"` you had `id="dod"`

```js
window.onload = function() {

    /******* EDIT 1 ********/
    // the heading element has no ID, so you need to add one, or use `querySelector` instead.
    //var para = document.getElementById("heading");
    
    var para = document.querySelector("heading");
    /***********************/
    
    para.innerText = "A short exercise on creating dynamic web content.";
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function () {
        alert("Ive been clicked");
    };

    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.onchange = function () {
        var item = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
        changeColour(item);
    };
    var dob = document.getElementById("dob");
    dob.oninput = function () {
        alert("Your birth date is:" + dob.value);
    };
    var range = document.getElementById("range");
    var value = document.getElementById("value");
    range.onchange = function () {
        value.innerText = range.value;
    };

    function changeColour(colour) {
        var c = 0;
        switch (colour) {
            case "Red":
                c = "#f00";
                break;
            case "Green":
                c = "#0f0";
                break;
            case "Blue":
                c = "#00f";
                break;
        }
        document.bgColor = c;
    };

    function daysOld(dob) {
        var msPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            now = new Date(),
            diff = now - dob;
        return diff / msPerDay;
    };

};
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab 11 suits</title>
    <script src="Lab1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<heading>
    <h1>
        HTML 5 Test Page
    </h1>
</heading>
<p id="test"></p>
<button id="button">Press Me</button>
<p/>
Colours:<select id="list">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<p/>
<!-- EDIT 2 -->
<!-- You had a typo on the id of your input 'dod' -> 'dob' -->
<!-- Your Birthday:<input type="date" id="dod"/> -->
Your Birthday:<input type="date" id="dob"/>

<!-- End EDIT -->
A Number: <input type="range" id="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">
<span id="value">1</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the var para = document.querySelector("heading") solved it. I dont understand why I have been told to do the other way though when it didnt seem to work. But thanks a lot Mobius.

Comment: the reason is because there is no element with id `heading` so what `querySelector` does is look for an element with the tag named `heading`.

querySelector can also look for ID's or Classes using the same syntax as CSS selectors.

Comment: @kmce does that answer your question?

Comment: ahh ok yes, i get it now. For the class we had just been given a lab sheet basically and told to copy it, i guess the lab sheet was slightly wrong. But yes I understand the issue now. Thanks alot :)